# I wrote a simple python website with socket but no output either an error?

Tags: python, sockets

I was watching a video about python and I wanted to try the code and that was after i make it for HTTP1.1:

```py
import socket
call = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
call.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
req= 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http://data.pr4e.org'. encode() #(method, url, body=None, headers={})
call.send(req)

while True:
    txt = call.recv(512)
    if (len(txt) < 1) :
        break
    print (txt.decode())
call.close()
```

but when i run this code i get no output

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong on multiple levels:

- Value of host header should be a host, not a URL.
- Host header has no end of line,. i.e. missing `\r\n`.
- There is no end of HTTP header delimiter, i.e. another `\r\n`.
- Reading the response is assuming that the server will immediately close the connection, even though HTTP/1.1 is used and thus implicit HTTP keep-alive is active, i.e. the server might wait for another request in the same TCP connection.

HTTP is not the simple protocol as it might look. Please read the actual standard before implementing it, see [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230).

Comment: Thank you, i did what you say and it works well now